# preg_replace using RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Here is a PHP code I'm struggling with:

```
<?php
    $sample = 'The quick brown fox';
    echo preg_replace("/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/", "$1", $sample);
?>
```

This RegEx aims to get rid of the last word of the string, and it surely did. But I don't understand how it works. Here are things that I know about this RegEx:

\W are non-word character 
\w are word character (0-9, _, a-z, A-Z)  
\w+ means that there are at least 1 word character 
\s is whitespace  
\s* means there may be 0 or more whitespaces 
(\W*)$ means ends with may be 0 or more non-word characters

Literally I know every character meaning in the RegEx, but with all combined, I have no clue why it can extract the word " fox". Also I don't understand what is $1 in the second parameter, I thought it should be "" as we are getting rid of the last word.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this is the `$` symbol - it anchors the rest of the expression to the end of the string.

So, starting from the end and working backwards we have:

- `(\W*)` - capture zero or more non-word characters. There are none, so this returns an empty string
- `\s*`  - Match zero or more white space characters. There are none.
- `\w+`  - Match one or more word characters, this matches the last word in the string
- `\W*` - Match zero or more non-word characters.

`preg_replace()` replaces the matched string with the contents of the replacement string, allowing for $1 to stand in for the first matched group, $2 for the second, etc. Thus we're replacing the matched string (`fox`) with the first captured group (an empty string), hence `The quick brown` .

Try plugging this into https://regex101.com and playing with it. I've set up a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cAu0z3/1)